# Automatically concat bower css

Tags: javascript, html, css, gruntjs, bower

In my source HTML I have:

```
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/angular-ui-notification/dist/angular-ui-notification.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/nya-bootstrap-select/dist/nya-bs-select.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
```

made with grunt wiredep, that works great. 
Moreover I want concat all this css to one file. I don't want to add this file manually in gruntfile.js. How can I use usemin or bower-concat to do this automatically. I'm doing the same with js file and everything works correctly.

For js I have

1.

```
wiredep: {

        task: {
            src: [
                'src/index.html'
            ]
        }
    },
```

In html

```
< !-- bower:js -->
< !-- endbower -->
```

2.

```
  bower_concat: {
        dist: {
            dest: 'src/temp/js/panel-dep.js',
            cssDest: 'src/temp/css/panel-dep.css',
            bowerOptions: {
                relative: false
            },
            mainFiles: {
                package: [ 'path/to/its/file.css' ]
            }
        }
    },
```

3.

```
uglify:{
      options:{
          manage: false
      },
        dist:{
            files:{
                'dist/js/panel.min.js': ['src/temp/js/**/*.js']
            }
        }
    },
```

Then I get nice working panel.min.js and HTML with link to this file